# Knockout bind string combine integer, why undefined?

Tags: string, knockout.js, numeric

My viewModel this..

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.model = {};
self.Message = ko.observable("");
self.model.CurrentDisplayAmr = ko.observable();
self.model.SelectedAmr = ko.observable();
self.model.CurrentAmrWirings = ko.observableArray([]);
self.model.CurrentSelectedWire = ko.observable();
self.model.AmrCommands = ko.observableArray([]);

//selected Amr is update here
self.selectAmr = function (item) {
    self.model.SelectedAmr(item);        
    self.GetAmrWirings();
};

//Amrs search is here
self.GetAmrs = function (searchTerm) {
    var self = this; // Retain scope of view model
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AmrSearch/SearchAmrs',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: ko.toJSON({ AmrNo: self.SearchAmrNo }),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {                
            $('#processing-modal').modal('hide');

            if (result.success) {
                self.model.CurrentDisplayAmr(result.data);
                self.Message(result.message);
            }
            else
                self.Message("Modem aramada sorun oluştu: " + result.message);

        },
        error: function (errorDetail) {
            $('#processing-modal').modal('hide');
            self.Message("Modem arama isteğinde hata: " + errorDetail);
        }
    });
}

Amr Selection html is here :
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input disabled type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0000000" data-bind="value: model.CurrentDisplayAmr.AmrRemoteId">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.selectAmr" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#processing-modal">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Seç
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

and if i bind text **self.model.SelectedAmr.AmrRemoteId** is no problem.

this code is ok :

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd" style="font-size: 38px;"></span> <a data-bind="text:model.SelectedAmr.AmrRemoteId"></a>
```

result is :
**00000012**

but if i change this :

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd" style="font-size: 38px;"></span> <a data-bind="text:'Selected Modem ' + model.SelectedAmr.AmrRemoteId"></a>
```

result is

**Selected Modem undefined**

why cant combine string and numeric value?

Comment: Although it's strange that your first construction works, in your second case you should use `'Selected Modem '+model.SelectedAmr.AmrRemoteId()`, i.e. you should evaluate your observable.

Comment: But i get error : Object doesn't support property or method 'AmrRemoteId' why not evaluate observable ?

Comment: Ok, that's why I wrote that it's strange. From your code snippet, it should be something like `'Selected Modem '+model.SelectedAmr().AmrRemoteId`, because `SelectedAmr` is observable itself. But I know nothing about `AmrRemoteId` - is it observable too?

Comment: i think AmrRemoteId isnt observable,

Comment: Well, then try solution from my previous comment - does it work? What errors does it show in console?

Comment: **Selected Modem '+model.SelectedAmr().AmrRemoteId** is Selected Modem undefined too.
and this codes doesnt any error result in console..

Comment: Update your question to include the part where you assign `SelectedAmr` with some data (that should obviously include `AmrRemoteId`). In your current code it's hard to say how first construction (`data-bind="text: model.SelectedAmr.AmrRemoteId"`) can even work.

Comment: I update question, adding other functions..

Comment: What is `item` in `selectAmr` function? Do you have a loop in your markup (hence using `$root`)? Have you tried logging `item` to console and see what does it contain?

Comment: Yes this is fault Ilya :)
Thanks..
I change it : **self.model.SelectedAmr(self.model.CurrentDisplayAmr());**
and SelectedAmr is fully observable and binding successfully.

Thank you. I fault with update it item object..